# Display none to React micro animations on component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

I have this component appear on button click. I was wondering whether there is a simple ease in then expand or popout animation. To make it look smoother in transition rather than appearing?

```
const CardExample = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick} type="primary">
        Show Card
      </Button>
      <Card style={{ display: show && "none" }}>This is my card</Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit lucid-star-fs6zi]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `opacity` instead of display here like below and use `transition` to add the animation

```
const CardExample = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  const cardStyle = {
    opacity: show ? 0 : 1,
    transition: "all 1s ease-in"
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick} type="primary">
        Show Card
      </Button>
      <Card style={cardStyle}>This is my card</Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit confident-morse-phg31]

Comment: I have updated my sandbox. I'm trying to ease in and expand. Do you know how to make it smoother? https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-star-fs6zi

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-flower-xj8k9

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer seems to get the job done, but I wrote up another way to do this with CSS instead of inline styles. You can conditionally apply a `className` and then handle the transition in a css file. The sandbox URL is at the bottom of this post.

```
import './CardExample.css';

const CardExample = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div className='card-example'>
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="primary">
        Show Card
      </button>
      <Card className={show ? 'showing' : 'not-showing'}>
          This is my card
      </Card>
    </div> 
  );
};
```

and then in the css file, you can have the following, which conditionally applies the visibility attribute on a 1 second animation interval.

```
.not-showing {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.showing {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visibility 1s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

I created a sandbox to demonstrate this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-boih3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Taking the first answer and yours. Do you know how to make the ease in and expand more smoother? https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-star-fs6zi

Comment: @Freddy. Yes, my code example had 1 second long transitions which make it much smoother.